# Replace no SQL - Caractere para manter uma parte do texto

Tags: sql, string

Preciso modificar uma parte no texto de uma tabela. Os registros de um email são **xxx@jf.gov.br** e preciso alterar todos para **jf.jus.br**. Só que a primeira parte do email não muda (o xxx).

Posso fazer um

```
update 
  TABELA 
set 
  email = REPLACE (email, '%.jf.gov.br', '%jf.jus.br').
```

Na verdade não sei qual o caractere coringa para manter íntegra a sigla do usuário (que vem antes da @).

Comment: Olá Josie, qual o seu Banco de Dados (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc)? Se possível atualize as tags incluindo o banco de dados específico.

Answer (score 10):

**PostgreSQL; MS SQL Server 2012; Oracle 11g; MySQL**

```
CREATE TABLE tabela(email VARCHAR(320));

INSERT INTO tabela VALUES ('eu@jf.gov.br');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES ('eula@jf.gov.br');

UPDATE
tabela 
SET
email = replace(email, 'jf.gov.br', 'jf.jus.br');
SELECT email FROM tabela;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c212f)

Note que sequer é necessário o `WHERE` pois o replace somente irá substituir se encontrar.

Porém se quiser poderá colocar a fim de evitar ["pegadinhas"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29508/replace-no-sql-caractere-para-manter-uma-parte-do-texto/29524#comment54938_29524) poderá fazer:

```
UPDATE
tabela 
SET
email = replace(email, 'jf.gov.br', 'jf.jus.br');
SELECT email FROM tabela;
WHERE RIGHT(email,9) = 'jf.gov.br';
SELECT email FROM tabela;
```

O será genérico e provavelmente funcionará na maioria dos bancos de dados. No entanto o **Oracle 11g** seria um exemplo de exceção pois, no mesmo em vez de `RIGHT(email,9)` deverá usar `substr(email,-9)`.

Comment: O problema de fazer uma *update* sem o `WHERE`, ainda que seja algo artifical, é de haver uma lista ou usuário do tipo `jf.gov.br.users@gmail.com`, com o `WHERE RIGHT` ou `REGEXP $` eliminamos qualquer pegadinha desse tipo.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly concordo, só que não acredito que haverá um caso desses. E fiz questão de mostrar o `where` para cobrir isto (caso o OP considerar necessário).

Answer (score 6):

No MySQL uma solução possível seria buscar através de REGEXP por todos os emails terminados em `@jf.gov.br`.

```
UPDATE  Tabela
SET     email = REPLACE(email, '@jf.gov.br', '@jf.jus.br')
WHERE   email REGEXP '@jf.gov.br$';
```

O caractere `$` é o marcador de fim da string.

[**Exemplo funcional no SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f183/1).

---

**Fonte**: [*SOen - Updating email addresses in MySQL (regexp?)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000612/updating-email-addresses-in-mysql-regexp)