# Alterar URL de todas as tabelas do SGBD MySQL com PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um SGBD MySQL com várias tabelas, procurei sem êxito como fazer uma rotina, preciso alterar todas as URL's de todas as tabelas para outra URL.

Ex: https://www.site1.com.br/ para https://www.site2.com.br/

Comment: Talvez possa te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/29508/89055

Comment: Assim seria um processo lento, pois existem mais de 30 tabelas no banco. Obrigado pela contribuição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a tabela information_schema.columns para extrair a lista de colunas e tabelas e montar as instruções update para executar individualmente. Exemplo:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('UPDATE ', table_name, ' SET ', column_name, ' = REPLACE(', column_name, ', ''xxx'', ''yyy'');')
FROM
    information_schema.columns
WHERE
    table_schema = '<SEU BANCO AQUI>'
    AND data_type IN ('char, ''varchar', 'text')
ORDER BY
    table_name,
    ordinal_position;
```

Comment: Tentei isso e não consegui, é novidade pra mim, alterei a url1 e a url2 e o nome do banco de dados, tentei no phpmyadmin executar o comando, deu um total de 18 resultados,  mas não alterou, no DB tem o information_schema, mas não sei como fazer uso de executar e montar as instruções.

Comment: Deu certo, opaaaa, vi que precisa imprimir o view do retorno, retornou diversos comandos SQL e os executei e foi com sucesso, obrigadíssimo.

Comment: Ótimo! Sorte e sucesso para você!